# Is it possible to use Google Admin SDK to remotely changing e-mail routing settings (advanced gmail settings)

Tags: google-admin-sdk

Does anyone know if it is possible to edit central routing mail settings with google sdk admin settings API or any other API? Or in any other way 'remotely' without using the google admin UI?

Specifically i'm interested in remotely editing the address lists that are used for policy routing (content compliance). I use these filters with address lists to re-route messages TO an address listed in there via a specific host. there are frequent changes to the addresses in these address lists, thats why i want to automate(script) this a bit so for example it reads an address list (txt/csv) file from my pc and imports this in the google address list (or it replaces the list).

Already found this documentation about admin sdk but i'm unsure how to use it and if it works for this purpose?: https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/admin-settings#managing_email_routing_settings

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you specify where in the Admin console you are currently changing these settings? I understand that you'd like to do this process via script instead?

Answer (score 0):

Sadly, the answer seems to be 'No'.

It's difficult to be definitive in saying 'No' as Google APIs are a sprawling beast, but certainly that API you point out can't be used for this purpose.

To the question from @lamblichus, to be specific (because I have the exact same need and check periodically to see if anything has changed) these lists are accessible through:

`Manage This Organisation (Admin Console) / Apps / Google Workspace / Gmail / Advanced Settings / [Select the Organization, if not the root]`

then in any of the categories like *Spam* (or *Blocked Senders*, *Attachment Compliance*, *Objectionable Content*, *Content Compliance*, etc.) you can Edit and in one of several possible places there are lists.

For example, under `Attachment Compliance / Show Options / A. Address Lists` it's possible to add an address to either *Bypass...* or *Only Apply...* the rule to a list of domains or email addresses.

There is where we too have to regularly maintain whitelists and blacklists and it's a real burden with very slow pages, with lots of sub-menus, non-deep linked pages, finicky controls and obtuse persistence model (when you make a change to those lists you are presented with THREE Save buttons!). I will probably end up trying to automate it with our UI automation tool, but I hold out hope that GCP API-focus will filter through.